# Copying files between Ubuntu and WIndows partitions

Tags: partitioning, windows, nautilus

Are there any particular problems associated with transferring files between Ubuntu and Windows (via Nautilus) or procedures that should be followed? I use a windows partition for using a scanner, then drag the files over from a data partition (or external HD) as and when I need them. I know this isn't ideal but are there issues I should be aware of when doing this?

Answer (score 2):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

> Using the File Manager
>
> For those using a desktop version of Ubuntu, or one of its offical
>   derivatives, the easiest and quickest way of mounting **NTFS** or FAT32
>   partitions is from the file manager: **Nautilus** in Ubuntu, Thunar in
>   Xubuntu, Dolphin in Kubuntu and PCManFM in Lubuntu. Simply look in the
>   left pane of the file manager for the partition you wish to mount and
>   click on it - it will be mounted and its contents will show up in the
>   main pane. Partitions show with their labels if labelled, or their
>   size if not.
>
> Unless you require your Windows partition - or a NTFS/FAT32 partition
>   for data shared with Windows - mounted every time you boot up for one
>   of the reasons given below, **mounting from the file manager in this way
>   should suffice**.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any particular problems associated with transferring files between Ubuntu and Windows (via Nautilus) or procedures that should be followed?

No, you wouldn't face any problems because of transferring files between Ubuntu and Windows partitions(via Nautilus).

But you can't be able to drop files to the Ubuntu root file system partition normally.You have to get superuser permission for that kind of oprations.

Comment: I am using 12.04 LTS as a standard set-up and simply open the mounted Windows partition and drag the file to the Ubuntu desktop folder without using the terminal. I'm not aware that I was using superuser - just the user settings from set-up from disc. They are all .tiff files.

Comment: yes you can be able to drop to the Ubuntu desktop but you can't be able to drop files to the `/` partition except `/home/$USER`.